# Где же эта инкапсуляция?

Tags: классы, c++

Небольшой уточняющий вопрос по классам C++.

Допустим, в классе есть метод. В этот метод передается параметр типа того же самого класса, в котором объявлен метод.

```
class A
{
...
public:
void Test(A& obj);
...
};
```

Методом проб и ошибок было установлено, что я могу спокойно изменять приватные члены класса, переданному в Test внутри метода. Я не понял, и где же тогда эта ваша инкапсуляция? Что-то в учебниках ответа не нашел, по каким тегам гуглить не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему класс не может изменять поля внутри себя? Легко может. Вот если бы по ссылке был передан другой класс, тогда не смог бы.

Comment: ТС имеет ввиду это:

        class A
        {
        private:
            int cash;
        public:
            void Test(A& obj)
            {
            obj.cash = 500;   // это.
            }
        };

        int main()
        {
            A a,b;
            a.Test(b);
            return 0;
        }

Comment: @vacsus, а Вы рассматривайте инкапсуляцию, как средство против *случайного* доступа не к тем данным, а не как метод "держать и не пущать"  и все станет понятно.

Более строго, компилятор проверяет возможность доступа в статическом а не в динамическом плане, т.е. он не различает разные экземпляры класса, которые появляются во время исполнения программы.

Comment: Как же так? Эта ваша инкапсуляция пропала, когда я передал в метод класса ссылку на тот же тип! Теперь вся эта оголтевшая толпа индусов может менять мои священные приватные переменные. Это предвестник конца. Шансов на спасение становится все меньше. А ведь рано или поздно они доберутся и до реализации, страшно даже представить что произойдет если это случится.

Comment: Если страшно за толпу индусов, то есть хорошие методы - абстрактный класс и pimpl.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Кажется разобрался

Answer (score 10):

Попробую объяснить доступными средствами что такое инкапсуляция.

Берем обычные механические часы - бьюсь в заклад, что 99% людей слабо представляют внутреннее устройство часового механизма - ну да там шестеренки, пружинки, маятник и проч. Но ведь все пользуются этими часами - индусы, китайцы, девочки, мальчики, пенсионеры, бандиты, президенты - в общем все. И все почему? Да потому что часы наружу выставляют 3-4 метода для работы с ними *инкапсулируя* в этих методах все свои пружинки, шестеренки и проч. винтики. Какие же это методы?

- Показать время
- Подвести стрелки
- Завести механизм
- Ну там подвести календарь, запустить секундомер и проч.

То же самое и с классами - инкапсуляция не означает полное скрытие данных, а это способ предотвращения бесконтрольного доступа.

Если вернуться к аналогии с часами, то инкапсуляция не есть священная корова - всегда найдется плохой мальчик, который вскроет заднюю крышку часиков и начнет туда-сюда крутить шестеренки.

Comment: Понятно. Суть в сокрытии деталей реализации а не защите от дурака. Но как написали в комментариях, меня интересовало именно данная ситуация, и оказалось что для компилятора у всех объектов одни и те же права доступа, что меня по началу смутило. Но все равно спасибо!

Comment: @Barmaley, креативно...классНО =)

Answer (score 6):

Инкапсуляция - это способ предотвращения бесконтрольного доступа к внутренним (=приватным) элементам объекта извне. Использование методов класса для работы с внутренними структурами - это и есть инкапсуляция, поскольку это есть контролируемый доступ к внутреннему пространству объекта: пользователь имеет доступ только к тому, что позволит автор, и только так, как позволит автор.

Comment: Зануда: беСконтрольного =)

Comment: Согласен. Надо меньше книг в старой орфографии читать.

Answer (score 4):

Кстати, в языке Scala поля класса можно делать доступными только для объекта-владельца, похоже это то, что хочет ТС.

```
class Foo {                                                                                                                                                                   
    private[this] var privateVar = 1

    def changePrivateVar() {
        privateVar = 2  // OK
    }

    def bar(foo: Foo) {
        foo.privateVar = 2 // Не скомпилируется
    }
}
```

Насколько мне известно, в C++ нет возможности подобным образом ограничить доступ к полям класса.

Comment: Все верно, в С++ настройка доступа происходит на уровне класса, а не на уровне объектов, как видимо того ожидал ТС.